# Load switch correctly wiring

Tags: microcontroller, switches, load

I need to use this load switch http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/docget.jsp?type=datasheet&lang=en&pid=TCK106G . This load switch will be controlled by an MCU. Since at startup MCU have floating pins(I suppose in every MCU), I want to ask if, to ensure that load switch will be always off until MCU decide to power it on, I should pull down CONTROL pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet covers two different types of chips. The TCK106G and TCK107G are active-high switches and include (see page 5) an internal mega-ohm sized pull-down resistor. This means that even if the control input is floating the switch will be held in the off position. However, this pull-down resistance is very high and you would be wise to add an external 10K-100K resistor as any noise or interference could overwhelm it and cause the switch to trigger unexpectedly.

If you are using the alternate TCK108G (active low variant) then you will need to fit an external pull-up resistor.

You are correct that most microcontroller ports are floated during startup, but you should carefully check the datasheet for your device as this is not always universal.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data sheet: -

[image]

It's clear I hope.

Comment: "However, this pull-down resistance is very high and you would be wise to add an external 10K-100K resistor as any noise or interference could overwhelm it and cause the switch to trigger unexpectedly." Thats a good answer.

Comment: @Yaro Please DO NOT quote other answers to me when YOU should have been capable of reading a data sheet and looking at the pictures.